# sqlite3 failing to create/insert table

Tags: python, sqlite

Im doing:

```
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('bags_of_coins.db')
        print('Db Creation Successful')
    except:
        print('Db Creation NOT Successful')
    try:
        conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE bags
            (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            bag TEXT    NOT NULL,
            );''')

        print('Table Creation Successful')
    except:
        print('Table Creation NOT Successful')
    try:
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO bags (bag) \
            VALUES ('test')");
        conn.commit()
    except:
        print('Insert NOT Successful')

    #finally.
    conn.close()
```

But it keeps outputting:

```
Db Creation Successful
Table Creation NOT Successful
Insert NOT Successful
```

Does anyone see anything i'm doing wrong? I was following this [guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm) but I cant see to spot the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Why not *remove* the blanket `try...except` and find out what exact exception is being thrown? It is *very rare* you actually need to use such Pokemon style exception handling (you normally *don't* want to catch em all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have comma before ) in this place:

```
CREATE TABLE bags
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
bag TEXT    NOT NULL,  <- here
);
```

delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sqlite3

conn = None
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bags_of_coins.db')
    print('Db Creation Successful')
except:
    print('Db Creation NOT Successful')
try:
    with conn:
        conn.execute("CREATE TABLE bags (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bag TEXT NOT NULL);")
        print('Table Creation Successful')

        cursor = conn.execute("INSERT INTO bags (bag) VALUES ('test')")
        conn.commit()
        print("Insert Successful" if cursor.rowcount > 0 else "Insert NOT Successful")
except:
    print('Table Creation NOT Successful')
```

Your error was creating the table.
The 'with' is a plus I added, it takes care of closing the connection when the block finish by any reason so you don't need the 'finally' block.

Don't hesitate to ask if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Blindly banging out try..except without showing the error from the exception is just going to cause you grief and heartache, use the exception available to list the specific error.

```
import sqlite3
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bags_of_coins.db')
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print('Db Creation NOT Successful', str(e))
mycursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE bags (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,bag TEXT NOT NULL)")
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("Table creation failed", str(e))
try:
    mycursor.execute("insert into bags (bag) values (?)", (['test']))
    conn.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("table insert failed", str(e))

#finally.
conn.close()
```